# How to assign range of cells to Range variable

Tags: vba, excel

My environment: MS Excel 2013

I want to assign range of cells to my range variable with code below

```
Dim strSourceFile As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook

strSourceFile = "D:\csv1.csv"
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strSourceFile)
Set rngY = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, RefCol), Cells(LastSource, RefCol))
```

I get error at last row while trying to assign value to `rngY`.

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells(2, RefCol)` is referencing the cells on the active worksheet.  You must qualify all the range objects.

Example 1:

```
Set rngY = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range( wbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(2, RefCol),  wbSource.Sheets(1).Cells(LastSource, RefCol))
```

Example 2:

```
With wbSource.Sheets(1)
    Set rngY = .Range( .Cells(2, RefCol), .Cells(LastSource, RefCol))
End With
```

Comment: Wow, Thomas, you saved my life <3 kiss kiss.

Comment: LOL...THanks for the check!